# how to start work with SQLite in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter

I've configured Codeigniter to work with SQLite, but I can't find where to start from. How to make a table in SQLite or whatever since it is not mysql where You can use phpmyadmin or command prompt client like it is in mysql... I have made database file in application/db/base.db   . step by step guide with examples or tutorial would be great, CI documentation doesnt give anything besides what driver to use and configure CI to work with SQLite. Thx in Advance

Comment: I usually use [Lita](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58) as a frontend for SQLite administration when im working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can write a controller that loads a model that creates them for you or you can use the firefox extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ or you can us SQLLite Manager :) http://www.sqlabs.net/sqlitemanager.php

Answer (score 0):

The below articles will help you somewhat...

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Introduction-to-CodeIgniter-Framework-P146.html